# Changing Gradle Compile .jar Path from Libs folder

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jar

I'd simply like to know, as the title states, how one would go about changing the Gradle Compiler output directory from the Libs directory, to a specific directory.

So, on build of my project, a compiled .jar file would be generated within a designated directory, by itself. This shouldn't be too hard to accomplish, though I've found no information on the topic, and me being a new Gradle user, I cannot seem to figure this one out.

I am aware that this is not a normally recommended thing to do, and many will not understand as to why I'd wish to do such things. Shortly, I am a Java Minecraft Server Plugin developer, and my development can only be tested when running a personal Testing Minecraft server locally. I want the compiler to output the jar file directly into the plugins directory of the Minecraft server.

Answer (score 0):

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    tasks.withType(Jar) {
        destinationDir = file("$rootDir/build/New_libs")
    }
}
```